# Install Apache with mod_wsgi to use Python for RESTful web services and Apache for web pages

Tags: python, apache, rest, mod-wsgi, mod-python

Can anyone help me install Apache with mod_wsgi to run Python for implementation of RESTful Web services. We're trying to get rid of our existing Java REST services with Apache Tomcat.
The installation platform is SUSE Linux Enterprise. Please provide a step by step installation procedure with required modules, as I tried it and everytime was missinhg one module or other either in Python installation or Apache installation.
I followed the standard Installation steps for all 3, Apache, Python and mod_wsgi, but didn't work out for me.
Would this work at all? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: "everytime was missinhg one module or other either in Python installation or Apache installation"  Vague.  Can you post a specific problem so we can focus.  The step-by-step is (1) install apache and (2) install mod_wsgi.  They're YUM archives.  There's nothing to it.  So please provide your specific error so we can diagnose that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if mod_wsgi is loaded as a module into the httpd.conf
2. Add apache host that points to a python/wsgi module which contains the 'def application' definition for your web-service.
3. Resolve any path issues that maybe arise from your import handling.

If this doesn't work, drop some error-dump here and we'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the specific thing I was trying:

Install apache & apr using YaST2, not by downloading the package from apache.org

Install python & python-devel using YaST2, not by downloading the package from python.org

Download the rpm package from http://software.opensuse.org/search?lang=en&p=2&q=mod_wsgi for your version of SLES.

rpm -i <"packagename">.rpm

restart apache : apachetl restart

.